# Progress bar for multiple audio player

Tags: javascript

I am working on creating a player in a page. In the page there will be multiple players. So progress bar needs to be shown for the current player that is being played. But the issue is when i play the player the progress bar is rendered in some other place because of multiple id's of the progress bar div. How can i target the progress div of the current player that is being played.
I am using javascript to render the progress bar.

Below is the HTML code: There will be multiple html blocks like below in different tabs of the page.

```
<div class="prabhata-play audio-playlist ">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <ul class="d-flex list-inline">
        <li>
            <button class="togglePlay" onclick="togglePlay('1445')" id="toogle1445">
                <img src="./play-round.svg" alt="play" class="play-img" id="playImage">
            </button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="title">Contentment in professional life</p>
                            <p class="auth-title">Swami Bhoomananda Tirtha</p>
                        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="d-inline text-end">
        <ul class="list-inline d-flex icons-sec">
            <li><img src="./video-list.svg" alt="video-list"></li>
            <li><img src="./heart.svg" alt="heart"></li>
            <li><a href="./AkashavallepaVidooragoham.mp3" download=""><img src="./download-icon.svg" alt="download"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="time-duration">0:39</span>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="progress" id="progress1445"></div>
<audio id="audio1445" class="audio-link" src="./AkashavallepaVidooragoham.mp3"></audio>
```

Javascript Code :

```
    function togglePlay (count, e) {

  e = e || window.event;
  var btn = e.target;

  var timer;
  var percent = 0;
  var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio"+count);
  audio1.addEventListener("playing", function(_event) {
  var duration = _event.target.duration;
    advance(duration, audio1);
  });
  audio1.addEventListener("pause", function(_event) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });
  var advance = function(duration, element) {
    var progress = document.getElementById("progress"+count);
    increment = 10/duration
    percent = Math.min(increment * element.currentTime * 10, 100);
    progress.style.width = percent+'%'
    startTimer(duration, element);
  }
  var startTimer = function(duration, element){ 
    if(percent < 100) {
        timer = setTimeout(function (){advance(duration, element)}, 100);
    }
  }

  if (!audio1.paused) {
    btn.classList.remove('active');
    audio1.pause();
    isPlaying = false;
  } else {
    btn.classList.add('active');
    audio1.play();
    isPlaying = true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, but I'm assuming the issue is from there being multiple divs with the same id on the page. To fix this, try using `document.querySelector()` [Documentation Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

For example, each player could be like this:

Html:

```
<div class="prabhata-play audio-playlist " id="player1">
   <div class="progress" id="progress1445"></div>
   <audio id="audio1445" class="audio-link" src="http://nat.verifinow.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/AkashavallepaVidooragoham.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

Then in the JS, you could access the progress div using:

`document.querySelector("div#player1 > div#progress1445");`

Comment: <div class="prabhata-play audio-playlist " >
   <div class="progress" id="progress1445"></div>
   <audio id="audio1445" class="audio-link" src="/AkashavallepaVidooragoham.mp3"></audio>
</div>
This entire div will be repeated multiple times on the page so adding the player1 id will cause the same issue I think.

Comment: No... if you change the id every time it will work. So each player has its own ID and you just need to know which player the song is in.